# Use constructor in place of atomic.store() when atomicity is not currently needed

Tags: c++, optimization, atomic, c++17, std

I use `std::atomic` for atomicity. Still, somewhere in the code, atomicity is not needed by program logic. In this case, I'm wondering whether it is OK, both pedantically and practically, to use constructor in place of `store()` as an optimization. For example,

```
// p.store(nullptr, std::memory_order_relaxed);
new(p) std::atomic<node*>(nullptr);
```

Comment: How is that an optimization? What about using some other variable in that part of the  code and then store the result in `p` when done.

Comment: @BoPersson I think plain store may be more efficient than atomic store. In my case, I need to store a value into the atomic. By program logic, no other thread would be reading/writing this atomic during this time. A plain store is therefore sufficient here.

Comment: This sounds like a trap for future maintainers (including yourself).

Comment: @PeteBecker: and one of the most well-hidden traps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accord with the standard, whether this works depends entirely on the implementation of `std::atomic<T>`. If it is lock-free for that `T`, then the implementation probably just stores a `T`. If it isn't lock-free, things get more complex, since it may store a `mutex` or some other thing.

The thing is, you don't *know* what `std::atomic<T>` stores. This matters because if it stores a `const`-qualified object or a reference type, then reusing the storage here will cause problems. The pointer returned by placement-`new` can certainly be used, but if a `const` or reference type is used, the original object name `p` *cannot*.

Why would `std::atomic<T>` store a `const` or reference type? Who knows; my point is that, because its implementation is not under your control, then pedantically you cannot *know* how any particular implementation behaves.

As for "practically", it's unlikely that this will cause a problem. Especially if the `atomic<T>` is always lock-free.

That being said, "practically" should also include some notion of how other users will interpret this code. While people experienced with doing things like reusing storage will be able to understand *what* the code is doing, they will likely be puzzled by *why* you're doing it. That means you'll need to either stick a comment on that line or make a (template) function `non_atomic_reset`.

Also, it should be noted that `std::shared_ptr` uses atomic increments/decrements for its reference counter. I bring that up because there is no `std::single_threaded_shared_ptr` that doesn't use atomics, or a special constructor that doesn't use atomics. So even in cases where you're using `shared_ptr` in pure single-threaded code, those atomics are still firing. This was considered a reasonable tradeoff by the C++ standards committee.

Atomics aren't cheap, but they're not *that* expensive (most of the time) that using unusual mechanisms like this to bypass an atomic store is a good idea. As always, profile to see if the code obfuscation is worth it.

Comment: to be honest, that tradeoff (absence of `std::single_threaded_shared_ptr` or something similar) is a bit questionable

Comment: ^^ it conflicts with the motto "don't pay for what you don't use"

Comment: @AndriyTylychko: Is it? How often do you copy `shared_ptr` in hot loops? Remember: copying a `shared_ptr` represents adding an additional shared owner to a piece of memory. Is that something that happens in performance-critical code that often?

Comment: what should we do in those rare cases?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko: Well, odds are good that if you're in performance-critical code that needs to share ownership of memory, then you've probably already done something wrong at the design level and should refactor it such that the operation is not necessary. Such refactoring will probably discover *other* inefficiencies inherent to the design. In the unlikely event that there is genuinely no way to avoid it... it's just two atomic increments. Lock-free atomics aren't the cheapest things in the world, but they're not going to utterly destroy your performance.

Comment: please don't get me wrong, as I said, it's just *a bit* questionable. Most game engines provide single-threaded shared ptr, performance-critical code is often a big part of them, and big chunks are designed to be executed in a single thread to avoid contention. Complexity and deadlines don't leave much resources for perfect design/implementation :(

Comment: Since `std::atomic<T*>` is required to have a trivial default constructor and destructor. I guess for this specialization, it is OK?